# javascript regex for repeated pattern

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have tried a number of combinations, But I am not able to zero it down. Not sure what am I missing. Thus seeking help.

here is what want to have

```
'hello AND AND NOT there AND NOT how NOT are you'.split(new RegExp(<expression>));
```

split like

```
["hello", "there", "how", "are you"]
```

But I am not able to zero it down. Any help is appreciated.

Here is what I have tried.

```
(AND\\s+)*?NOT
(AND\\s+)+?NOT
(AND\\s+(?=(AND\\s+)+))+?NOT
AND.*NOT
```

**EDIT**
My apologies for not being clear. I want the splitter to be (AND(SPACE: zero or more time)){this whole pattern zero or more time}(Followed by NOT)

Would love to get it done using plain javascript.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the match group you need? Will it always be AND and NOT? Are there any other words?

Comment: I have edited the question for splitter. It shall be number of (ANDs followed by random number of spaces )followed by NOT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on new requirements:

```
/(?:\s*(?:AND\s*)*)NOT\s*/
```

Usage (with `filter` to cleanup the empty strings caught!):

```js
var str = 'hello AND AND NOT there AND NOT how NOT are you';
var x = str.split(/(?:\s*(?:AND\s*)*)NOT\s*/).filter(String);
document.write(JSON.stringify(x));
```

Comment: You need a filtering post step with this regex

Comment: The filtering could be simply `.filter(String)`.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I update the splitter in the question.

Comment: @TyagiAkhilesh Updated the pattern above.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Thanks man/woman. Works like a charm. I wonder why I could not figure this one out. I tried everything except ?: pattern. I guess I need to study more about that. Accepting your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var str = "hello AND AND NOT there AND NOT how NOT are you";
var tempArry = str.replace(/AND|NOT/g,'');
tempArry = $.trim(tempArry).split("\s+");
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = tempArry;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: can we try with pure javascript ?

Comment: just remove trim function, it will work.just write `tempArry = tempArry.split("\s+");`

Comment: So this is what it effectively becomes.
'hello AND AND NOT there AND NOT how NOT are you'.replace(/AND|NOT/g,'').split("\s+")

Its not producing the desired result.

Comment: you can try this 
`'hello AND AND NOT there AND NOT how NOT are you'.replace(/AND|NOT/g,'').split("\s+")[0].split(' ')`

Comment: but it'll return empty values too. you have to use a  loop to remove it.